# Proof of induction from higher starting point

Tags: proof-verification, induction, peano-axioms

I'd like to request to verify this proof that for a arbitrary natural $n_0$ this holds:
$[C(n_0+1) $ and $\forall n>n_0 : C (n) \implies C (n+1)] \implies \forall n> n_0 : C (n) $
($C (n)$ means a condition)

At first it seemed easy but I haven't yet proved that there aren't any naturals between n and n+1 etc nor any other properties of naturals, which makes me unsure of the correctness of my proof.
All I can use is peano axioms and addition. So here it is:

Assume $C (n_0+1) $ and $\forall n > n_0 : C (n) \implies C (n+1)$

Let D (n) be a condition: $D (n) \iff (n>n_0 \implies C (n))$

i)  $D (0)$ is obviously true since 0 cannot be bigger than $n_0$ therefore the implication is true.

ii) Assuming $D (n) $we have to prove $D (n+1)$

$n>n_0 \implies C (n)     $ (ind. hypothesis)

$\forall n>0 : C (n) \implies C (n+1)$

The previous 2 lines thus give: $n>n_0 \implies C (n+1) $

Since $n+1>n $ we get finally

$(n+1>n_0 \implies C (n+1)) $

Is this correct ? Is there a better aproach?

Comment: In your first it should be $C(n_0)$.  If you use $n_0+1$ as your base case you can only get $\forall n \gt n_0+1 \ldots$

Comment: " I haven't yet proved there is no natural number between n and n+1. "..... Nothing is provable about  $\Bbb N$ without a definition of it. What def'n and what axioms are you starting from?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Peano axioms

Answer (score 2):

We wish to show that the condition $C(n)$ holds for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > n_0$ given that $C(n_0 + 1)$ holds and $\forall n > n_0: C(n) \implies C(n + 1)$.

Consider the set $T = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n > n_0 \wedge C(n)~\text{does not hold}\}$.  We must show that $T = \emptyset$.

Suppose $T \neq \emptyset$.  Since $T \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, then $T$ must have a least element by the [Well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle).  Call it $t$.  Since $C(n_0 + 1)$ holds, $t \neq n_0 + 1$, so $t > n_0 + 1$.  Hence, $t - 1 > n_0$.  Since $t$ is the smallest element of $T$, $C(t - 1)$ holds.  Since $t - 1 > n_0$, $C(t - 1) \implies C(t)$, contradicting our assumption that $t \in T$. Hence, $T = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to define a new variable $m=n-n_0$ and a new predicate $E(p)$ such that $E(p)\equiv C(p+n_0)$.  Then you have $E(0)$ and $E(m)\implies E(m+1)$ and can use the induction axiom as usual.